# Optional @Pathvariable in REST controller spring 4

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-restcontroller

I'm writing a Rest Service (HTTP Get endpoint), where in the below uri does the following

```
http://localhost:8080/customers/{customer_id}
```

1. fetch the details for the customer_id passed in the uri
2. if the customer_id is not passed (http://localhost:8080/customers), fetch all the customers details.

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "customers/{customer_id}")
public List<Customer> getCustomers(
@PathVariable(name = "customer_id", required = false) final String customerId) {
LOGGER.debug("customer_id {} received for getCustomers request", customerId);

}
```

However, with the above code, for the second scenario control is flowing to  getCustomers().

Note: I'm using Java8 and spring-web 4.3.10 version

Highly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optional `@PathVariable` is used only if you want to map both `GET /customers/{customer_id}` and `GET customers` into single java method.

You cannot send request which will be sent to `GET /customers/{customer_id}` if you don't send `customer_id`.

So in your case it will be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/customers", "customers/{customer_id}"})
public List<Customer> getCustomers(@PathVariable(name = "customer_id", required = false) final String customerId) {
    LOGGER.debug("customer_id {} received for getCustomers request", customerId);
}
```

> public abstract boolean required
>
> Whether the path variable is required.
>
> Defaults to true, leading to an exception being thrown if the path variable is missing in the incoming request. Switch this to false if you prefer a null or Java 8 java.util.Optional in this case. e.g. on a ModelAttribute method which serves for different requests.

You can use `null` or `Optional` from java8

Comment: value = {"/customers", "customers/{customer_id}"}) is it ant style.

Comment: Thanks @ByeBye.. Works like charm.

Comment: @ByeBye Just noticed any issue when I gave the request mapping values as array. I had registered a class level request mapping, and the method level request mapping is like the below:
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = {"/", "/{customer_id}"}).  the endpoint is returning a 404 when I call http://localhost:8080/customers (without a trailing slash). Any clue on what's going wrong here.

Comment: @ByeBye how could PathVariable can take parameters like required false/true?. Its giving compile time error for me

Comment: @RajeshHatwar https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html docs say that parameter is present.

Answer (score 1):

This may help someone that is trying to use **multiple optional path variables**.

If you have more than one variable, you can always accept multiple paths.
For instance:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"customers/{customerId}&{startDate}&{endDate}",
"customers/{customerId}&{startDate}&",
"customers/{customerId}&&{endDate}",
"customers/{customerId}&&"
})
public Customer getCustomerUsingFilter(@PathVariable String customerId, @PathVariable Optional<Date> startDate, @PathVariable Optional<Date> endDate)
```

Then you would call this URL using all the **path separators** (in this case &)

Like 
GET /customers/1&& or
GET /customers/1&&2018-10-31T12:00:00.000+0000 or 
GET /customers/1&2018-10-31T12:00:00.000+0000& or 
GET /customers/1&2018-10-31T12:00:00.000+0000&2018-10-31T12:00:00.000+0000

Answer (score 0):

You should create two end-point here to handle the individual request :

```
@GetMapping("/customers")
public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
LOGGER.debug("Fetching all customer");  
}

@GetMapping("/customers/{id}")
public List<Customer> getCustomers(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
LOGGER.debug("Fetching customer by Id {} ",id);  
}
```

`@GetMapping` is equivalent to  `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` and  `@GetMapping("/customers/{id}")`  is equivalent to `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "customers/{id}")`

Better approach would be like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
    LOGGER.debug("Fetching all customer");  
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Customer getCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    LOGGER.debug("Fetching customer by Id {} ",id);  
    }
```

Comment: I initially did this, but both the java methods are intended to do the same operation. I was looking for a single java method which avoids code duplication. Was looking for somwthing like what  @ByeBye was suggesting