# Endpoints with Same header values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have two rest endpoints.

So if I pass format value the first endpoint should be called and I don't pass format value the second endpoint should be called

1. `/record/{id}/{lcid}.{format}`
2. `/record/{id}/{lcid}`

If I pass the format value, even then the second endpoint is called.

If I pass a Accept header and no format value then second endpoint is called

In every case the second endpoint is invoked.

Here is my code

```
@GetMapping(value = "/record/{id}/{lcId}.{format}",
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                        MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,                                                                         
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_RDF_XML, 
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_RDF_XML})
public ResponseEntity<String> getWithFormat(
            @PathVariable String id,
            @PathVariable String lcId,
            @PathVariable (value = "format") String format,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

      ....
}


@GetMapping(value =  "/record/{id}/{lcId}",
            headers = {ACCEPT_HEADER_JSON, 
                       ACCEPT_HEADER_APPLICATION_RDF_XML, 
                       ACCEPT_HEADER_RDF_XML,                        
                       ACCEPT_HEADER_APPLICATION_XML},
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,                        
                        MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, 
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_RDF_XML, 
                        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_RDF_XML})
public ResponseEntity<String> getwithHeader(
            @PathVariable (value = "id") String id,
            @PathVariable (value = "lcId")String lcId,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        ...
}
```

**The ACCEPT_HEADER_JSON = "Accept=" + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;**

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would refactor that if I were in your shoes. Such ambiguous mappings are complicating both usage and maintenance of the API. TBH I am surprised spring has not failed on startup with ambiguous mappings error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optional @Pathvariable in REST controller spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567364/optional-pathvariable-in-rest-controller-spring-4)

Comment: the format is supposed to be the response representation. like .json or .rdf. So I can not have it as a request param. Let me try with single endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution here is to combine both endpoints into one. You could make the `.{format}` an optional part of the path, but it's even nicer to just turn it into an optional query parameter:

```
 @GetMapping(value =  "/record/{id}/{lcId}",
             headers = {ACCEPT_HEADER_JSON, 
                        ACCEPT_HEADER_APPLICATION_RDF_XML, 
                        ACCEPT_HEADER_RDF_XML,
                        ACCEPT_HEADER_APPLICATION_XML},
             produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                         MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,
                         MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, 
                         HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_RDF_XML, 
                         HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_RDF_XML})
 public ResponseEntity<String> getwithHeader(
            @PathVariable("id") String id,
            @PathVariable("lcId") String lcId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String format,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        ...
 }
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you would need to add `?format=jpg` to get it into a RequestParam

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand Yes, exactly. A query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp to limit what characters are allowed in each of the PathVariables. So for lcId you would allow all characters except for the dot. Like this

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}/{lcid}.{format}")
    public void withFormat(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("lcid") String lcid, @PathVariable("format") String format) {
        System.out.println("format");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}/{lcid:[^.]+}")
    public void withoutFormat(@PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("lcid") String lcid) {
        System.out.println("no format");
    }
}
```